# Whats the Java EE package naming convention?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, package

I've been trying to grasp a better understanding of which features belong to the Java EE specification and which are standard java features of a new application that I'm working on, and I've noticed that the package structure seems to be a bit muddled.

An example, take the packages:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
```

Both of these are enterprise features however only one make s it obvious by existing in the `enterprise` package.

In the Java EE API specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/overview-summary.html) I notice that only some of the features are held within the `enterprise` package.

My guess is that some of the packages were around before the EE edition of Java, so they kept the structure for backwards compatibility? Still.. it all seems a little odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some APIs in the JavaEE stack are not specific to JavaEE and are also usable in JavaSE. For example CDI which provides dependency injection, which you have in your question `javax.inject.Named`, can be used in a JavaSE application as well.